# C# Use object's property rather than reference for List.Contains()

Tags: c#, list

I have something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>()

// ... Populate myList

if (myList.Contains("testType"))
{
  // Do something
}
```

In the above code, I want `myList.Contains()` to match on the Type property rather than the MyClass object reference. How do I achieve this? Do I use the `IComparable` or `ICompare` interface, do I override `MyClass.Equals()`, or is it sufficient to override the string cast of MyClass?

Edit: After doing some tests with overriding `Equals()` and the string cast of `MyClass`, implementing `ICompare` and `IComparable`, I have found that none of these methods work. Actually, it seems like what would work is if I were to override the `MyClass` cast of string, something like `myList.Contains((MyClass)"testType")`. However I think I like The Scrum Meister's answer better :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method:

```
if (myList.Any(x => x.Type == "testType"))
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: hhmmm...definitely simpler than mine ;)

Comment: P.S. make sure you add the using System.Linq; at the top of the .cs file -- this has tripped me up a few times :-)

Comment: Very elegant. That's definitely going into my code snippets library. I actually realised after posting the question that my Type strings must be unique throughout my list, so I ended up using a `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In additional to @The Scrum Meister's answer, if you are using C#2.0 you can use [`List<T>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)

```
MyClass target = myList.Find(m => m.Type == "testType");
if (target != null)
{
  // Do something to the target
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you will basically override the `Object.Equals()` method. According to MSDN you should explicitly override the Object.Equals method. You can then do something like:

```
void Add (MyClass testCls)
{
    var myCls = myList.Where(x => x.Equals(testCls)).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

    if (myCls == null)
    {
            // then myList does not contain the object you want to add
            myList.Add(testCls);
    }
}
```

For more on `IEquatable<T>`: [MSDN IEquatable(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)
The advantage to this is that you are actually checking against the `Type` property of other list contents - if that is what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on The Scrum Meister's answer, the condition you provided won't even compile, if I am reading it correctly.  You're seeing if a list comprised of MyClass objects contains a string, so that won't work.

It seems like what you really want to do is check and see if any instance of a MyClass object that is in that list has a Type property that matches your desired type.

For clarity's sake, though, I'd redefine the MyClass class like so:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Type MyType { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then your condition would be:

```
if(myList.Any(x => x.MyType == typeof(SomeClass)) { // put the real class name in the typeof()
    // Do something
}
```

Hope that explains things a bit clearer.

Comment: My "Type" isn't a C# Type... it is an employee type which I'm reading from a CSV, for example "Retail", "Support", or "Accounts". I don't know if that makes any difference to your suggestion?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just prefer the readability of the type conversion.  Should you need to get a type from a string, you can use `Type t = Type.GetType(String typename)`